# Composition of two gradients

Tags: android, shader, gradient

I'm trying to make a composition of two gradients.

```
int startColor = 0x0000ff00;
int endColor = 0xff00ff00;
float angle = 45f;
```

Gradient 1:

```
SweepGradient sweepGradient = new SweepGradient(d/2, d/2, new int[]{startColor, endColor, endColor}, new float[]{0, angle/360f, 1f});
```

[image]

Gradient 2:

```
RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(d/2, d/2, d/2, startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

[image]

Result:

```
ComposeShader composeShader = new ComposeShader(sweepGradient, radialGradient, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

[image]

I expect that result's alpha is **multiplication** of 1 and 2 alphas. For example, upper edge of sweep should be fading, like in 1. Why it's sharp?

What's wrong?

**Solved!**

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink),
adding `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` solves the problem.

Comment: most likely its [hwd accel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) issue

Comment: You right !
Adding setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) solves the problem !